# How is one approach more Pythonic than the other?

Tags: python

Apparently

METHOD 1

```
if var in ['string one', 'string two']:
    do_something()
```

is more Pythonic than:

METHOD 2

```
if var == 'stringone' or var == 'stringtwo':
    dosomething()
```

Why is Method 1 considered more Pythonic than Method 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> To be Pythonic is to use the Python constructs and datastructures with clean, readable idioms.

From: [*What is Pythonic?*](http://faassen.n--tree.net/blog/view/weblog/2005/08/06/0)

Simply put, the first is easier to read than the second - it has less boilerplate, and less overhead than the first. Any Python programmer can look at the first and see that there's a list of things being checked against, and it reads much more like plain English than the second. Consider if you expanded the list of things being checked against - the first example would read like:

```
if var in ['string one', 'string two', 'string three']:
    # If var is one of string one, string two, or string three.
    do_something()
```

while the second would sound like:

```
if var == 'stringone' or var == 'stringtwo' or var == stringthree:
    # If var is equal to stringone, or var is equal to stringtwo, or var is equal to stringthree.
    dosomething()
```

Answer (score 5):

It's easier to extend the first approach to more strings:

```
if var in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']:
```

The second approach quickly becomes unwieldy:

```
if  var == 'one' or var == 'two' or var == 'three' or ...:
```

In addition, the first approach can be used to test a function call's return value, and only evaluates it once:

```
if bigCalculation() in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
```

The second approach must re-evaluate the call each time, leading to worse performance (especially if the call is computationally expensive).

```
if bigCalculation() == 'one' or bigCalculation() == 'two' or ...:
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes sense in a practical way, and it shows me how the first method is more efficent. Although it doesn't directly answer how Method 1 is more Pythonic than Method 2. Thank you anyways! Your answer combined with the other answer provide a good read and a better understanding of the two methods (the other one in a Pythonic sense, and yours in a practical sense).

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: I think it clearly describes why Method 1 is more Pythonic than the other one.